# Toggle pages backgroundcolor in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

On my HTML/CSS page I need to have a switch to toggle the background color and text color. (for example black theme to white theme). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this :

```js
$("#toggleTheme").click(function(){
$(".container").toggleClass("black");
});
```

```css
.container {
 background: #fff;
 color: #000;
}
.black {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="toggleTheme">Toggle Theme</button>

<div class="container">
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
 <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
   $(document.body).toggleClass("black");
});

CSS:

body { background-color: white; }
.black { background-color: black; }
```